# Semi group presentation $<a, b | a^{2} = b^{2} = 0, aba = a, bab = b>$

Tags: relations, semigroups, group-presentation

Another semi group question here, trying to get my head around the topic.

Consider the semi group $S=\left<a, b | a^{2} = b^{2} = 0, aba = a, bab = b\right>$

I need to prove that $S$ has order $5$.

The way I did it was to consider $a$ and $b$: we have to apply either $a$ or $b$ to these elements so $a.a=0$ and $a.b=ab$ $b.a=ba$ $b.b=0$ gives us three new elements for so far we have $\{a,b,ab,0,ba\}$.  Now consider $ab$: we have to apply either $a$ or $b$ to this; applying $a$ we get $aba$ which is $b$ so not a new element; applying $b$ we get $abb=0$ so not a new element. Finally consider $ba$ (as we know applying $a$ or $b$ to $0$ gives $0$): applying $a$ to $ba$ we get $0$; applying $b$ to $a$ we get $ab$ which gives us no new elements.

Thus we have at most $5$ elements; are they all distinct though! I mean I can see they are but how do we know that say $ab \neq ba$ or whatever? How can I show that all these elements are distinct?

Cheers guys

Comment: Using $1$ for the identity (and guessing that's what $0$ is in your presentation), note that $ab = abaa = aa = 1$ and $ba = babb = bb = 1$.

Comment: Is this also true for semigroups? As we are only dealing with sets that have an associative operation here, there is no need for inverses or identities.

Comment: abaa only equals babb because $a^{2}$ and $b^{2}$ are zeros in our semigroup.. definition of a zero in a semi group, $a$ is a zero if $ab=a=ba$

Comment: We arent talking groups here just semigroups there need not be a 1, infact i dont think there is.

Comment: Ahh ok, no zero isnt the identity in this presentation, its a zero of a semigroup

Comment: Oh, $0$ is absorbing here?  (So $0x = x0 = 0$ for all $x$?)

Comment: Yeah, this is the definition we have been given of a semigroup having a "zero" but yes $0$ is absorbing here

Comment: OK.  Then you can show the rewrite system given by making the long side of each equation rewrite to the short side in your presentation is confluent by considering all overlaps of distinct long sides.  This implies that all words that are reduced according to your rewrite rules are distinct.

Comment: I am quite new to this, could you please explain what that means?

Comment: Make up four rules.  Each rule is of the form $foo \to bar$, and it means that, if I have a word with $foo$ as a subword, I can replace $foo$ by $bar$ in it.  The four rules here are $aa \to 0$, $bb \to 0$, $aba \to a$, and $bab \to b$.  This is called a term-rewriting system.  It's confluent if you get the same result no matter which order you apply the rules.  It's sufficient to check only the words that are overlaps of two rule left-hand sides (this is "Newman's lemma").  So check you have a confluent TRS and that all 5 of your words are reduced and you're done.  (I'll make this an answer.)

Comment: Thank you very much, not totally sure what overlaps of two rule left-hand sides means though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The machinery of term-rewriting systems is useful here.  A term-rewriting system is a bunch of rules of the form $foo \to bar$ where $foo$ and $bar$ are words.  The rule $foo \to bar$ means that one can rewrite a word such as $qwefoorty$ to $qwebarrty$ by replacing an instance of $foo$ of our choosing in the word by $bar$ at the same position.

A word is called reduced with respect to a term-rewriting system if none of the rules of the term-rewriting system match any subword of the word.  Reducing a word means applying rules of the term-rewriting system until you get a reduced word.

A term-rewriting system is called confluent if the order of application of rules does not matter---a TRS is confluent if every word corresponds via rewriting rules to a unique reduced word.

Suppose no infinite chain of reductions is possible for any word.  Newman's lemma states that a term-rewriting system is confluent if and only if there is no word that can be reduced in a single step to two different words that cannot be reduced to the same word.  (That is, if $a \to b$ or $a \to c$ in a single step, then there is a $d$ that both $b$ and $c$ can be reduced to.)

The critical pair lemma states that it's sufficient to check only the words that are overlaps of two left-hand sides of rules to prove "local confluence," which is the hypothesis of Newman's lemma.

In your example, you have the rewrite rules $aa \to 0$, $bb \to 0$, $aba \to a$, and $bab \to b$.  (I made the longer side reduce to the shorter side so that there are trivially no infinite reduction chains.)

We need to check all overlaps of two rule left-hand sides.  An overlap is a word of the form $uvw$ such that $v$ is nonempty and $uv$ and $vw$ are each left-hand sides of rules.  The possible overlaps are $aaba$, $abaa$, $bbab$, and $babb$.  Note that $aaba \to 0ba$ or $aaba \to aa$; both words can be reduced to $0$, so there is no failure with $aaba$.

The reasoning for the other three words proceeds similarly; it follows that this rewriting system is confluent.  So two words are distinct if and only if they reduce to the same thing, which means we need only enumerate the reduced words.  You already did that.

Comment: There is an error in my list of rewrite rules; $0a \to 0$ and $0b \to 0$ and $a0 \to 0$ and $b0 \to 0$ also need to be there.  But everything still works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a presentation of the Brandt semigroup $B_2$, which can be described 
as the semigroup generated by the two following matrices
$$
 a = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 b = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}, 
$$
under the usual multiplication of matrices. Thus $B_2 = \{a, b, ab, ba, 0\}$ with
$$ 
 a = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 b = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 ab = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 ba = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The relations $a^2= 0$, $b^2 = 0$, $aba = a$ and $bab = b$ are trivially satisfied.